# Dirty on command?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access 2010 application that has a form with a text box and a command button on it.  Clicking the command button places a default value in the text box.

Question: When a user clicks the command button I can either:

1. Run an SQL update to save the new text box value in the data source that it is bound to plus set the `me.textbox1.value` to its new value, or
2. Run the same SQL update to save the new text box value in the data source that it is bound to plus do a `form.requery`?

Which is better? Would changing the bound value in the data source initiate a current event and an automatic requery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the entry immediately, I would write the value to the text box, and do

```
Me.Dirty = False
```

to save the record in the bound form.

I see no point in doing this via SQL.

> Would changing the bound value in the data source initiate a current event and an automatic requery?

No, that would actually be the worst method. The form wouldn't know about the changed data source, and once the user would start editing, he would get the "Write Conflict" message.

Your 1. would have the same problem.

Comment: Hi Andre, Thanks for your comment. So setting me.textbox1.value and  me.dirty = false in the click event of a command button would have the effect of saving the new text box value to its respective data source  thus making an SQL update pointless because the data in the table would have already been changed (assuming the me.dirty = false appears in the VBA before the SQL)?

Comment: @Taffy: Exactly. You can simply try it out by opening the table in a second window, then press Shift+F9 after executing the code.